# Azure service bus queue for multiple regions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

We have a requirement with a low latency solution that should deliver a message to the customer queue in multiple regions. We will use the Service bus queue for it.
[image]

In this case, we need to have an 'instance' of service bus queue for each region, it is possible to use one instance of service bus and create a region-specific queue (just to reuse resources of service bus as we plan to use premium tier) or do we need to create separate instances of service bus for each region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple region specific queues with the same Service Bus namespace. A namespace is associated with a single region only.